# Aligning elements in a RelativeLayout such that one is center_horizontal

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Here's the layout:

[image]

As you may notice from the layout above, the outer layout is a `RelativeLayout` in which all the elements are centered horizontally. This layout contains another layout which is also a `RelativeLayout` grouping a few elements. I wanted this group to be centered vertically.

Now the question is about the two elements shown in the inner `RL2`. They are basically a button and a progress bar (circular). I want the button to be centered horizontally and the progress bar to be just next to it; i.e. `progressBar.Left = button.Right + 10` (just a reference).

I have spent the last couple of hours trying to figure out something but I have nothing. (Also, very new to layout design on Android).

Please let me know if I can be more helpful.

---

EDIT: What I have tried —

1. Horizontal linear layout -> can't center the button in a linear layout and adjust supplementary margins for progress bar.
2. Relative Layout -> Unable to make anything happen here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to replicate the layout you wanted and came up with this:

it works for me

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            >

        <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#FF5722"
                />

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

            <View
                    android:id="@+id/view1"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:background="#0288D1"
                    />

            <View
                    android:id="@+id/centered"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/view1"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:background="#0288D1"
                    />

            <View
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/centered"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/centered"
                    android:background="#B58105"
                    />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: looks like this]

Comment: :slow clap: Thanks a lot. This is an exceptionally easy way of doing this. I should just go and read some more docs on this.

Comment: would things change if I want the mustard box to be centered (now vertically) with the blue box; only in case their height is different.

Comment: @p0lAris I don't think it's possible to do that with `RelativeLayout`, maybe you should take a look at `PercentRelativeLayout` or you can programmatically translate (setTranslationY method) the mustard box down by the amount of (the blue box's height - mustard box's height)/2

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the button and progress bar in a Horizontal LinearLayout.  Relativelayout becomes unwieldy as per my experience if you start nesting them.

Comment: I have tried a whole bunch of things and this includes having a linear horizontal layout and making the button center_horizontal but that does not work (in linear layout). Can you be a bit more specific. Probably an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach for such requirement: [image: Layout sample]

The red squares are invisible [`<Space>`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) elements which should have the same width/height as your progress bar. This also means you need to wrap each row in a horizontal `LinearLayout` and wrap all of that in a vertical one.

In terms of efficiency, this might be not ideal. I consider it acceptable for one page or two.

Updated for @p0lAris comment:

To center the elements in the middle, you could use a `layout_weight` attribute (= 100), and use fixed width for the `<Space>` and `<ProgressBar>` elements.

This would mean the button is as wide as possible.

If a further padding on start/end is required, the padding attribute could be added to the parent layout which contains all the button rows.

Comment: How do you make the middle element (button) centrally horizontal?

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. This seems like a lot of work. I just went with @MohMah's answer as it seems to tackle it perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes it is a lot of work. I usually go with such "complicated" solution to make things work stable on all sorts of phones and screen sizes, without the need to adjust too many width parameters. Glad you solved your problem!